# primefaces ui-g dynamic height

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm using Grid CSS of primefaces.
I have two columns with one row at left and two rows at right.
I'm trying to give the height of my left row to my right rows.
This is my test code :

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12" style="background: red;">
        <div class="ui-g-6" style="background: blue;">
            TEST1
            <!-- Repeat TEST1 * 100-->
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-6" style="background: purple;">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-12" style="background: green;">TEST3</div>
                <div class="ui-g-12" style="background: gray;">TEST4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In my result, I still see red background. I need to have a green background which replace the red background. In the primefaces [sample layout](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml), the "menu" column have the same height of rights rows.

Do you have an idea ? Thanks :)